# Pandas: filling NaNs only in rows intervals for which lower bound is given

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.Dataframe` with multiple missing values. I would like to fill (backfill in this case) only intervals for which I give the lower bound. I made it work with the following code. I was wondering if the for loop can be avoided and the process speeded-up (I work with several millions of rows).

```py
import copy
import pandas as pd

# Values
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), 6, 7, 8,
          float('nan'), 10, 1, 2, 3, float('nan'), float('nan'), 7]

# Pandas data frame to use
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': values}, index = range(0, len(values)))

# Intervals to fill lower bound list
start_filling_indices = [4, 15]

# Copy the data frame
df_filled = copy.deepcopy(df)

# Filling the intervals
for i in start_filling_indices:

    i_stop = df['A'].iloc[i:].first_valid_index()
    # +1 is required to include i_stop in the interval
    df_filled['A'].iloc[i:i_stop + 1].fillna(method = 'backfill', inplace = True)
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Please explain a little bit. Also, post input & output data-frames as text in the question for easy visualization.

Comment: @Antoine Collet: Is the solution below working for your purposes? In case you need more information or it is not completely what you were searching for, please share some more details with us. If the answer is helpful, please consider closing the question by accepting the answer.

Comment: @Lepakk, this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution without for-loops:

First I create a new DataFrame with the Start-indices, then I evaluate, at what indices I have to change the value, and what value that would be.

```
new=pd.DataFrame({'Start':start_filling_indices})
new['filluntil']=new.apply(lambda row: df.iloc[row.Start:].first_valid_index(),axis=1)
new['indices']=new.apply(lambda row: np.arange(row.Start,row.filluntil),axis=1)
new['fillwith']=new.apply(lambda row: df.A.iloc[row.indices[-1]+1],axis=1)
```

Now I use the explode-feature to make a new Dataframe, that is just consisting of the rows that should be altered in the next step:

```
new2=new[['indices','fillwith']].explode('indices').set_index('indices')
```

For demonstration purposes, I copy the original data into a separate column in the DataFrame and then apply the information from the new2-DataFrame.

```
df['filled']= copy.deepcopy(df)
df.filled.iloc[test.index]=new2.apply(lambda row: row.fillwith,axis=1)
```

Then I get the original data and the manipulated data in one dataframe

```
Out: 
       A  filled
0    1.0     1.0
1    2.0     2.0
2    3.0     3.0
3    4.0     4.0
4    NaN     6.0
5    NaN     6.0
6    NaN     6.0
7    6.0     6.0
8    7.0     7.0
9    8.0     8.0
10   NaN     NaN
11  10.0    10.0
12   1.0     1.0
13   2.0     2.0
14   3.0     3.0
15   NaN     7.0
16   NaN     7.0
17   7.0     7.0
```

Note, that the explode-feature is only available from Pandas version 0.25.0, as this cost some time for me to find that out.